# Black bars on all sides when running iPhone app on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an iPhone app and I am trying to run it on iPad. But when I run I see black bars on all the sides as shown below:

[image]

I am using a LaunchScreen.storyboard file. The LaunchScreen.storyboard is set as launch screen (checkmark is checked). In the target settings I have the following settings:

[image]

Any ideas?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit: That apple tester got it wrong. your app is good !!!

I created a new project that only support an iphone and ran it on the ipad simulator. I calculated the ratio of the screen inside it is equal to 0.69. the same as the ratio of the screen inside the screen shot sent to you by apple.

> Apple tester got it wrong. looks like that is the new behaviour on the
>   iOS 10 and that apple test does not know it. reply to them with this
>   they should accept your app without resubmitting new binary.

### Original Answer:

**Deleting DerivedData, Clean and remove app from simultator should solve the problem. Or maybe you didn't support iPad:**

[image]

Comment: Yeah I don't support iPad. It is only for iPhone but should it not fit the screen completely even if it is an iPhone app running on iPad. The 2X mode still shows the black bars on all sides.

Comment: No it doesn't. it appears as it is iPhone. and you can click the 2X button on the screen thats all.

Comment: So 2X should not fill the complete iPad screen? My app got rejected by Apple and that is what they said.

Comment: what exactly did they say? and where did they say that?

Comment: Here is what Apple said in their reply to App review: Performance - 2.4.1


We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.2.1.

Please see attached screenshots for details.

Comment: can you add the screenshot they attached?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138420/discussion-between-hasan83-and-john-doe).

Comment: Thanks! I resubmitted the app again. hopefully they will approve it. Thanks a million for your help!

Comment: if they returned to you with same error. reply to them with wht I mentioned on the edit answer. good luck

Comment: I just added what you said in my reply to Apple.

Comment: you said that you submitted the app again :)

Answer (score 0):

Its because of app is only for iphone, thats why if you are run in iPad it shows actually iphone's view, Enable for ipad and then check.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple tester did not likely get it wrong. Check the following:

- Go to your app's target. In the `General` tab, look at the `Deployment` section. What is listed for `Devices`? If it says *Universal*, change it to *iPhone*.
- Go to your `info.plist`. Remove any keys pertaining to the iPad. (*Supported interface orientations (iPad)* may be there, for example.)

Now, your app should run correctly on an iPad, even though it was made for iPhone only.