# iPad pro doesn't open my app in full screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

There will be a black margin when my app open via iPad pro 12.9
How can I fix it? Built the app using xcode 9.4 as well as 10.1 and both are same. No issue for other iPads the issue happens only for iPad pro

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Comment: this might be help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878434/black-bars-on-all-sides-when-running-iphone-app-on-ipad

Answer (score 3):

Because you did not add the `LaunchImage` for `iPad 12.9`. and there is no option in assets to add `LaunchImage` for `iPad 12.9`. So I suggest that you should use `LaunchScreen.storyboard` instead of `LaunchImage`.

A better way that you should create two different `LaunchScreen.storyboard`( One for `LaunchScreen~iPhone`, Second for `LaunchScreen~iPad`) in a project. add both `storyboard` set in `info.plist`

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName~ipad</key>
<string>LaunchScreeniPad</string>
```

Then set full-size image set in `LauchScreen.storyboard`. and set Launch screen file is LaunchScreen~iPhone(Default).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding iPad to my Supported Destinations. Initially it wasn't there. So I believe as a result, the iPad simulator was displaying the app as though it is running on an iPhone.

Comment: This answer would be more clear if it explained where to find the Supported Destinations setting or included a screenshot of the setting.