# App will not run full screen on iPad Pro 12.9 inch simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Using Xcode 12.4. My App will not fit the full screen when run on an iPad Pro 12.9 inch simulator. It runs in a box within the screen, with a black border on each side. I have tried various suggestions from stackoverflow and elsewhere. The target "Deployment Info" selects iPhone and iPad. Built for iOS 12.

I do have a LaunchScreen.storyboard. And my info.plist has the following.

```
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
```

I tried modifying my info.plist as shown below, as it was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116867/ipad-pro-doesnt-open-my-app-in-full-screen) as a possible solution. This didn't work - but note I set the same launch screen for both iphone and ipad:

```
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName~ipad</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
```

Can anyone suggest the cause for this problem? Or point me to some current documentation on how to correctly configure this.The App runs fine on iPhone simulations and real iPhones. My launch screen was coded a few years ago. What magic command or setting is needed these days?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a brand new project... add a "Hello World" label to the default view controller... run the app on 12.9" simulator, and see if it fills the screen. If it does, compare the details between that app and your current one.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my own problem. I'm posting the solution in case it's useful to someone else. Note that before the solution the App always worked full screen on phones. In the past it worked full screen on iPads.

To get full screen I had to change a storyboard segue. I have a seque that shows a Navigation Controller - this nav controller must be full screen. The storyboard segue in the past was Kind = Show. I changed it to Kind = Present Modally, Presentation = Full Screen. And like magic the nav controller is now full screen on the simulator 12.9 inch iPad.